# Jersey FormData, upload multiple file data

Tags: javascript, java, rest, jersey

I have written a Rest Service in Jersey to upload a Multiple Files. As shown Below. But i want the attribute name i.e name="metadata" and name="file "  in Restservice class.

```
        Select XML file 1: <input type="file" **name="metadata"** size="45" accept=".xml" />


        Select PDF file 2: <input type="file" **name="fileak**" size="45"  accept=".pdf" />
```

Select XML file 1:

Select PDF file 2:

```
@POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response uploadFile(
            @FormDataParam("file") List<FormDataBodyPart> parts) {
        for (FormDataBodyPart part : parts) {
            FormDataContentDisposition disp = part
                    .getFormDataContentDisposition();
            InputStream in = part.getValueAs(InputStream.class);
        }

        return Response.ok(" uploaded successfully !!").build();
    }
```

FormDataContentDisposition  only pulls the content type , file name from the form and not the input type name="" attribute.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

I am posting an request using HTML as show below.

Posting the HTML file as wel.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding" />

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#uploadBtn").click(function()
            {
                $('input[type="file"]').each(function(index, value)
                {   


                  var nameValue=value.attributes[0].value;
                  var file = value.files[0];

                    if(file)
                    {
                         var formData = new FormData();

                        formData.append('file', file); 
                        //formData["name"] = nameValue;

                        $.ajax({
                          url : '/publicationservice-web/v1/publication/upload',
                          type : 'POST',
                          data : formData,
                          cache : false,
                          contentType : false,
                          processData : false,
                          name:nameValue,
                          success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                var message = jqXHR.responseText;
                                $("#messages").append("<li>" + message + "</li>");
                          },
                          error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                $("#messages").append("<li style='color: red;'>" + textStatus + "</li>");
                          }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>NGBulletin Upload System - Metadata and PDF</h1>

    <form action="v1/publication/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <p>
            Select XML file 1: <input type="file" name="metadata" id="metadata" size="45" accept=".xml" />
        </p>
        <p>
            Select PDF file 2: <input type="file" name="fileak" id="fileak" size="45"  accept=".pdf" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <input id="uploadBtn" type="button" value="Upload PFD Files" />
        </p>

    </form>

    <ul id="messages">   
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing is, the value in `@FormDataParam("file")` *is* the name. You use this when you want all the parts extracted by name. For instance you can have

```
post(@FormDataParam("metadata") InputStream metaIn,
     @FormDataParam("metadata") FormDataContentDisposition metaFcd,
     @FormDataParam("fileak") InputStream fileakIn,
     @FormDataParam("fileak") FormDataContentDisposition fileakFcd) {
}
```

But if you want to iterate through all the parts yourself, you should use `FormDataMultiPart` instead of `List<FormDataBodyPart>`. You can get the map, with the name as the key. Also the name is provided in the `FormDataBodyPart.getName()`. For example

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadAsset(FormDataMultiPart multipart) {

    Map<String, List<FormDataBodyPart>> map = multipart.getFields();

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<FormDataBodyPart>> entry : map.entrySet()) {

        for (FormDataBodyPart part : entry.getValue()) {
            InputStream in = part.getEntityAs(InputStream.class);
            String name = part.getName();
            System.out.println("--- name: " + name);
        }
    }
    return Response.ok("cool upload").build();
}
```

The point is that it is pretty pointless to try and obtain the name (programmatically) if you are going to use `@FormDataParam` annatotion, because you are ultimately already hard coding the name (in the annotation value), so you already know it.

Comment: Hi PeesKilet..i have added my HTML as well, Can you please have a look....seems like the code just returns my "file" and "file " and not the name attribute i.e metadata and fileak

Comment: You need to append them as parts. You are only adding one part (the "file" part). The "metadata" and "fileak" should be different parts.

Comment: Or actually, looking again, you are iterating (`$('input[type="file"]').each)`) through all the `"file"` types and making a separate ajax request for each field. You should probably combine them in one request

Comment: For instance, declare the `FormData` before the loop. Append in the loop, then after the loop, make the request

Comment: In your Javascript you will also need to get the value from the "name" attribute of each input element. All you are doing is append a hard coded "file". In your HTML, you don't even have an input element with the name "file". It should be `formData.append(name, file)` inside the loop

Comment: Or I don't know, maybe you want to send a different request for each file. Either way, the you should get the name from the "name" attribute, and use _that_ to append to the FormData. Not a hard coded "file". Then you can't use `@FormDataParam`, because you need a hard coded name value. And without the annotation, you can only use `FormDataMultiPart`, where you need to extract the single part yourself.

Comment: Got it...but the last question ...how to pass the variable.var nameValue=value.attributes[0].value; retuns string in doube quotes not '' quotes....

Comment: Do `var nameValue = value.attr('name')` Then just do `formData.append(nameValue, file)`

Comment: And another thing. If you are only going to send one file at a time, the name shouldn't matter. It's only use to differentiate the different parts when there are multiple parts. If you send both parts at the same time, then you can just go with the first example, since you already know the names.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your explanation...Ok pretty muck clear....But can know how to pass the var nameValue in single quotes....as var nameValue = value.attr('name') didn't work ..expects a function. Can you please have a look into the posted HTMl

Comment: Also Just to clarify and confirm....if it a single request..i should go with post(@FormDataParam("metadata") InputStream metaIn,
     @FormDataParam("metadata") FormDataContentDisposition metaFcd,                                                                                                            CORRECT?
     @FormDataParam("fileak") InputStream fileakIn,
     @FormDataParam("fileak") FormDataContentDisposition fileakFcd) {
}

Comment: Sorry, use `$(value).attr("name")`. And yes to the second question.

Comment: Hi PeesKillet....Works like Charm......it works man.......Thanks a lot for your Quick replies.......Last and the final question i suppose for this thread. Can i know how to send the two file in one post request in HTML for the example you explained earlier

Comment: Just create the `FormData` outside the loop (`each` function). Then inside the loop just append each file to it. The after the loop, send the request. Currently you are doing everything _inside_ the loop, so a request is sent for each input element

Comment: Thanks peeskillet for you quick responses....I din't expect that i will get the solution so quickly

Comment: I am new to JUNIT test cases, Can you please tell me how to write JUNIT for below jersey code.  post(@FormDataParam("metadata") InputStream metaIn,
     @FormDataParam("metadata") FormDataContentDisposition metaFcd,
     @FormDataParam("fileak") InputStream fileakIn,
     @FormDataParam("fileak") FormDataContentDisposition fileakFcd) {
}

Comment: I tried with i have used the File resourcesDirectory = new File("src/test/resources/pdf");
  resourcesDirectory.mkdir();
  String pdfcopyLocationString = resourcesDirectory.getAbsolutePath()
    + "/";
  File filepdf = new File(pdfcopyLocationString + "sample.pdf");
  File filexml = new File(pdfcopyLocationString + "test.xml");

  

  given().multiPart("fileakFcd", filepdf).multiPart("metaFcd", filexml)
    .expect().body(equalTo("OK")).when()
    .post("/path/upload");

Comment: @Paul Samsotha can you please help with the question i posted just now. Tagged you in the other thread.